# Query timeout expired when trying to run a short procedure

Tags: excel, ado, vba

Here's my connection string:

```
Global Const strConn As String = _
    "PROVIDER=SQLNCLI10;" & _
    "P-SSWORD=blahblah;" & _
    "USER ID=blahblah;" & _
    "INITIAL CATALOG=blah;" & _
    "DATA SOURCE=blah;" & _
    "CONNECT TIMEOUT=0;" & _
    "COMMAND TIMEMOUT=0" & _
    "PACKET SIZE=4096;"
```

And here is the simple code:

```
Sub MoveDataUsingADO()

Dim cn As Object
Dim cm As Object
Dim rs As Object

    'get in touch with the server
    'Create ado objects.
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.connectiontimeout = 0
cn.Open strConn
cn.CommandTimeout = 0

Set cm = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set cm.ActiveConnection = cn
cm.CommandType = 4 'adCmdStoredProc

Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Set rs.ActiveConnection = cn


cm.CommandText = "WH.dbo.ourProcName"
With wb.Sheets("Data")
    .Activate
    .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(Excel.xlUp).Row + 1, .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(Excel.xlToLeft).Column)).ClearContents
End With
With rs
    .Open Source:=cm.Execute '<=====errors here===========
     wb.Sheets("Data").Cells(wb.Sheets("Data").Rows.Count, 1).End(Excel.xlUp)(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
    .Close      'close connection
End With
...
...
```

At the point marked above I get the following error:

[image]

I don't understand - the procedure takes 55 seconds to run and throughout my `vba` I have set timeouts to `0`... I thought this forced them to *not* expire?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Have you tried setting the time out explicitly on the command?

```
cm.CommandTimeout = 0
```

Rather than setting it on the connection. I think the connection timeout deals with how long it lets you try to establish a connection before it rejects while the command timeout is how long you command has to execute.

Comment: +1 thanks for this information - `cm.CommandTimeout = 120` is the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have some idea how long it should take your query to execute? Might there be a different problem than the timeout period?

You should try setting the timeout on the command object like this:

```vb
cm.CommandText = "WH.dbo.ourProcName"
cm.CommandTimeout = 120
With wb.Sheets("Data")
    .Activate
    .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(Excel.xlUp).Row + 1, .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(Excel.xlToLeft).Column)).ClearContents
End With
With rs
    .Open Source:=cm.Execute '<=====errors here===========
     wb.Sheets("Data").Cells(wb.Sheets("Data").Rows.Count, 1).End(Excel.xlUp)(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
    .Close      'close connection
End With
```

Comment: +1 thanks for this information - `cm.CommandTimeout = 120` is the solution.